# Unable to link mgprint.lib in wince6.0 application

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-ce

I am trying to print text from MFC application, developed by using custom SDK of OSDesign. 
I am using `StartDoc()` and `EndDoc()` API calls in my application, but I didn't find the declaration of these api's. So i searched for wingdi.h files in Wince600 installed folder and found wingdi.h file in location C:\WinCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\SDK. So included that one in my project so now, it has declaration of `StartDoc()` etc, but when I am trying to link it with mgprint.lib it is giving me linking error.  I have taken mgprint.lib file from C:\WinCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\LIB\ARM4I\DEBUG or RETAIL.

Any pointers will help us.

Answer (score 1):

You should not just take header files and libs files from the `PUBLIC` folder if they are not actually part of your OS design/SDK. I would recommend to use only the files that you get on your `cesysgen` folder as result of your catalog configuration. You should get printing support on your OS design by including SYSGEN_PRINTING. See this [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932925.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks, But we are able to print the file from WordPad application given by Wince. The only problem we are facing is how to print the DC through our own MFC application. Means we have data ready on DC of window, just wanted to print it that on prinetr. Pls anymore clue.. Regards,
Mukesh

Comment: I do not know what else could be wrong, maybe you could post some code? Are you calling StartDoc and StartPage functions? Take a look at this link, it may give you some hints in case you are missing something: http://www.mooseworkssoftware.com/printing.htm